# How can I save data from an external file into a 2D array? (C++)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, fstream, ifstream

I'm making a simple console game in C++ and I would like to be able to read a map from a .txt file and save it as a 2D array. I believe something like this is possible using fstream.
I'm also not sure whether it is possible to create a 2D array's size based on how large the map is from the external file.

I am trying to get it to work a bit like this:

---

.txt file in which i'm taking map from:

11111
10001
10001
10001
11111

---

The actual 2D array:

```
char map[][] = { {1,1,1,1,1},
                 {1,0,0,0,1},
                 {1,0,0,0,1},
                 {1,0,0,0,1},
                 {1,1,1,1,1} }
```

---

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to C++ so I don't quite understand everything yet. This is one of my first times reading from an external file so don't expect much from me :)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Consider `std::ifstream`. It functions just like `cin` but for files.

Comment: Array sizes must be compile-time constants, so you have to use `std::vector`, ideally by wrapping it in some class to make a vector behave like a 2D map (a vector of vectors is very inefficient). For reading the file, I would recommend you to learn about file I/O from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539) since we don't teach broad topics like this from scratch here (nor do we write code for people). Instead, we like to help people with their existing attempts at solving a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to have a good read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, add the input file(e.g. input.in, input.txt) in your project.
Initiate a new stream to read data from that file.
Read the numbers row by row and put the numbers in the matrix.

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream f(“input.in”);//declare the stream

int matrix[num_of_rows][num_of_columns];

void read(){
for(int i=0;i<num_of_rows;i++)
for(int j=0;j<num_of_columns;j++)
f>>matrix[i][j];}
```